# How to refer textfield name in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, textfield

I am trying to autofill information from a database into text fields when the user selects the specific name. I initialized the text fields with unique names that are dynamically added.

This is the table for the form:

```
  <form name="senarai" id="senarai">
        <div class="container table-responsive col-lg-10">
          <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered" id="demo_table" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">#</td>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-3">Nama</td>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-2">No Personal</td>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Department</td>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Telefon</td>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Ext</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>

      </form>
        </div>
      </div>
          <!-- buttons -->
        </head>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
            <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The javascript below added the text field dynamically. It contains a selection field and text fields which will be filled with information grabbed from the database.

```
 <script>
 count=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var markup = '<tr><td class="col-lg-3"><input type="checkbox" name="rekod"></td>';
        markup +=  '<td class="col-lg-3"><select id="nama'+ count +'" name="nama[]" class="form-control"><option value="">Choose</option><?php foreach($nama as $key => $value):echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.addslashes($value).'</option>'; endforeach; ?></select></td>';
        markup +=  '<td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="nopersonal'+ count +'" value="test"></td>';
        markup +=  '<td class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" name="jabatan'+ count +'"></td>';
        markup +=  '<td class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" name="telefon'+ count +'"></td>';
        markup +=  '<td class="col-lg-1"><input type="text" name="ext'+ count +'"></td></tr>';
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
        count++;
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="rekod"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});    
</script>
```

This is a javascript code to autofill the text fields.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function ()
 {
        $(document).on('change','#nama'+ count +'',function(){
           var ID = jQuery(this).val();
           if(ID)
           {
              jQuery.ajax({
                 url : 'add_demo/get_nama/'+ID,
                 type : "GET",
                 dataType : "json",
                 success:function(data)
                 {
                    console.log(data);
                        alert($('input[name="nopersonal'+count+'"]').val());//the problem is here
                        $('input[name="jabatan'+count+'"]').val(data.JabID);
                        $('input[name="telefon'+count+'"]').val(data.notelttp);
                        $('input[name="ext'+count+'"]').val(data.ext);  
                 }
              });
           }
           else
           {
              $('input[name="nopersonal"'+count+']').empty();
              $('input[name="jabatan'+count+'"]').empty();
              $('input[name="telefon'+count+'"]').empty();
              $('input[name="ext'+count+'"]').empty();
           }
        });
});
</script>
```

I cannot put id on the text fields, it creates problems and warning in the console. I tried to use text field name property but the dynamic name  *"nopersonal'+count+'"* cannot be identified.

When i tried this:

```
  alert($('input[name="nopersonal'"]').val()); //i put test value in the textfield
```

The text field can be identified and the value appears in the alert.

How I can fix this issue? Thank you.

edited:
I had added a few rows, and the html as follows

```
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="nopersonal1" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="jabatan1" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="telefon1" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="ext1" value="test"></td>

   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="nopersonal2" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="jabatan2" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="telefon2" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="ext2" value="test"></td>

   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="nopersonal3" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="jabatan3" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="telefon3" value="test"></td>
   <td class="col-lg-2"><input type="text" name="ext3" value="test"></td>
```

The textfield name is in sequence as it should be.
But if you notice, there are 14 'inputs' in console without '+count+'. If I put id with '+count+' there is console with repeatitive 14 elements non unique id.

```
  selector string: input[name="nopersonal"] selected element: n.fn.init(14) [input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "input[name="nopersonal"]"]
```

I am not sure the cause of it. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('input[name="nopersonal'+count+'"]').val());//the problem is here
```

Have you tried building the selector first as a string, `console.log`ing it to confirm that it looks right, and *then* passing it in to jQuery? I'm wondering if there might be an issue with `count` for some reason. If it were just a number, JS would be interpolating it into the string before it ever became a jQuery problem.

EDIT:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url : 'add_demo/get_nama/'+ID,
  type : "GET",
  dataType : "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //   Changes
    const selectorString = 'input[name="nopersonal'+count+'"]';
    console.log("selector string: ", selectorString, "selected element: ", $(selectorString));
    alert($(selectorString).val());
    //   /Changes
    $('input[name="jabatan'+count+'"]').val(data.JabID);
    $('input[name="telefon'+count+'"]').val(data.notelttp);
    $('input[name="ext'+count+'"]').val(data.ext);  
  }
});
```

Comment: I see..I don't know on how to build the selector..can you show an example to guide me? Thank you

Comment: I feel that count needs to be redefined inside the ajax block because for some reason external variables cannot be used in ajax block

Comment: I'll put in some sample code for what I'm talking about.

Comment: alert shows 'undefined'.. the console --> selector string:  input[name="nopersonal2"] selected element:  n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "input[name="nopersonal2"]"]

Comment: selector string:  input[name="nopersonal"] selected element:  n.fn.init(14) [input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "input[name="nopersonal"]"]

Comment: above is the console if I remove '+count+' variable

Comment: Based on that last answer, it seems like there are a bunch of elements being created with the name property set to "nopersonal", but if I'm understanding the way "add row" is supposed to work, shouldn't they all have names like "nopersonal1", "nopersonal2", etc?

Can you try adding some lines and then share the actual HTML that's being produced on the page?

Comment: If I change the text field name into array? nopersonal[ ], can I make reference to the field.